# TabControlRegionAdapter bindings in the tab header are broken under silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight-3.0, prism

This used to work fine under SL3 beta, but after I upgraded to SL3 RTM, the functionality stopped working.

In order to reproduce, just open and compile the ViewInjectionComposition solution in Quick starts. the tab header that used to display "Current Projects", now is empty.

has anyone else encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2:

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4599

UPDATE:

I think the issue is this, taken from the Silverlight Toolkit 3 page:

HeaderedContentControl
Breaking Change: Moved from Silverlight 3 Beta SDK to Silverlight 3 Toolkit July 2009.

I am using references to compiled DLLs for my CAG libraries, so I will try recompiling those and let you know what happens.

ORIGINAL:

Yeah - it's busted. Looking into the fix now... Not really helpful, I know - just wanted to confirm the issue.